# Error with React Menu - Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: reactjs, menu, antd

I'm new to React so bear with me.

I'm trying to build out a side menu navigation.  This is the beginning of the application so I will be adding more nav titles in the future.  To future proof, I'm trying to store the key/labels for the item tags in an array.  Within React render, I'm trying to iterate over the array and insert the key/label accordingly.  However, I'm running into the below error.  Line 41 corresponds to `key: menuItem["key"];`.

Why do I see this error and how do I fix it?

`Line 41:11:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`

```
import '../../src/index.css';
import { UploadOutlined, UserOutlined, VideoCameraOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Layout, Menu, theme } from 'antd';

const { Header, Content, Footer, Sider } = Layout;

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const {
    token: { colorBgContainer },
  } = theme.useToken();
  const menuItems = [
      {
          key: "nav1",
          label: "Nav 1"
      },
      {
          key: "nav2",
          label: "Nav 2"
      }
  ]


  return (
    <Layout>
      <Sider
        breakpoint="lg"
        collapsedWidth="0"
        onBreakpoint={(broken) => {
          console.log(broken);
        }}
        onCollapse={(collapsed, type) => {
          console.log(collapsed, type);
        }}
      >
        <div className="logo" />
        <Menu
          theme="dark"
          mode="inline"
          items={menuItems.forEach((menuItem) => {
              key: menuItem["key"];
              label: menuItem["label"];
              })
          }
        />
      </Sider>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your code.

The first is the syntax error that is caused by `{ }` in JavaScript being both the function body syntax and object syntax.

In the context of an arrow function `() => {}` the `{ }` means you are opening up the body of the function. This means you have to `return` from the body instead of it being implicit (no function body).

To correct this, you can simply wrap the function body in parenthesis so that it treats it as an implicit return, and treats the `{ }` as an object instead:

```js
(menuItem) => ({
  key: menuItem["key"];
  label: menuItem["label"];
})
```

The second problem is that `forEach` does not accept a return value. You need to use `map`.

```js
items={menuItems.map((menuItem) => ({
  key: menuItem["key"];
  label: menuItem["label"];
}))}
```

### Note

Unless your code is simplified for the question's sake, your loop is completely unnecessary. You are mapping the objects into new objects that have the same values.

If this is truly the case, you can remove this completely from your code and just do `items={menuItems}`.

Comment: That was all wonderfully helpful.  As for the redundancy, I expect a lot more requests for stakeholders that will complicate navigation.  Though in the meantime, referencing the array is the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are looping inside the Menu component. Try this solution.

```
  {menuItems.forEach(menuItem => {
    <Menu
      theme="dark"
      mode="inline"
      items={{
        key: menuItem.key,
        label: menuItem.label
      }}
    />
  })}
```

Comment: Looping inside a prop expression is not a problem. Your proposed code will not return anything (see my answer on `forEach` and implicit returns) and if changed to `map` it would render several independent menus, which does not seem to be the desired outcome

Comment: @Brian Thompson
Yes, you are right. I have go through the code of the ant design Menu component. The items prop of Menu directly accepts the array and iterates on it automatically so I think there is no need to iterate. Trying items={menuItems} may resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try this way

```
 {items.forEach(menuItem => {
    <Menu
      theme="dark"
      mode="inline"
      key={menuItem.key}
      label={menuItem.label}
    />
  })}
```

When you do a foreach, it traverses each object "{}" and to access the array of object that is traversing you use the point like "menuItem.key" and in React you put it like this "{menuItem.key}".

So if i have one array like this:

```
 const menuItems = [ // array open
  { // object open
      key: "nav1",
      label: "Nav 1"
  }, // object close
  { // another object open
      key: "nav2",
      label: "Nav 2"
  } // another object close
  ]  // array close
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work.

Comment: This just adds a second syntax error by trying to do `key: {menuItem.key}`